# Appcelerator titanium issue when listing a directory content

Tags: filesystems, directory, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to list all the files contained in a directory (which path is : [resources folder]/Images/InputImages/).

here is my code :

```
var path = Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'Images'+ Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'InputImages';

var imgDirectory = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(path);

Ti.API.info(imgDirectory.nativePath);
//display the right path, I mean  Resources/Images/InputImages

var imagesArray = imgDirectory.getDirectoryListing();

Ti.API.info(imagesArray.length); // display 4, since I only have 3 images and 0 hidden files

for(i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++)
{
    Ti.API.info(imagesArray[i].name); //displays <null> for each element.
}
```

What is wrong? What is correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code which solved my problem :

```
var imagesArray = [];
/////////////////////////
var dirFullPath = Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'Images' + Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'InputImages';
var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(dirFullPath);

var dirItems = dir.getDirectoryListing();

for ( var i=0; i<dirItems.length; i++ ) 
{
    var itemFullPath = dirFullPath + Titanium.Filesystem.separator + dirItems[i].toString();

    var item = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(itemFullPath);

    if(IsImage(item.name))
        {imagesArray.push(item);}
}
/////////////////////////
```

Comment: with IsImage a hand-written function.